# Magento 2 - add condition rule block in custom grid

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to add condition rule block in my custom grid.
I want to use it as a filter and want to search products using condition rules.

I used this [link](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/)
 as reference.